# Class operator '=' definition

Tags: c++

In namespace MySpace I have created my custom string class:

```
namespace MySpace {
    const std::string bws = "hello";

    class string {
        public:
            std::string s ;
            string(void) :s(bws) {}
            string(const std::string & _s ) : s(bws) {};
            operator std::string & (void) {return s;}
    };
}
```

I do assign `MySpace::string f` to `std::string d`.

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    MySpace::string f("ddd");
    std::string d=f;

    std::cout<<d<<std::endl;
}
```

Why does this work? I haven't define operator `=` for MySpace::string?

And why it doesn't work when I remove operator `&` definition from `MySpace::string` (line `operator std::string & (void) {return s;}`) ?

`&` is not `=`

Comment: You aren't defining a `&` operator, you're defining a conversion operator that returns a `std::string&`. Did you intend to define `&` as a concatenation operator or something?

Comment: `std::string d=f;` doesn't even use `operator=`.

Comment: If `const std::string bws = "hello";` is in a header file, it creates a duplicate of the string for every source file that includes it, wasting memory. To fix, declare in header as `extern const std::string bws;` and in one source file as `extern const std::string MySpace::bws = "hello";`

Comment: `MySpace` has been deprecated with C++11. You should consider upgrading to `Facebook` or `Twitter`.

Comment: In `std::string d = f;`, the `=` is not an operator. It is part of the syntax for specifying an initalizer as part of a declaration. It has the same effect as `std::string d{ std::string(f) };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have implemented a convertion operator:

```
operator std::string & (void) {return s;}
```

It basically tells the compiler how to convert a `MySpace::string` into `std::string&`.

The `&`means reference here, the "`operator`" you are overloading here is "`operator std::string`", not "`operator &`". (This is of course not very pedantic).

For more details see:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: It tells the compiler how to convert a `MySpace::string` into `std::string &`, **not** `std::string`. The difference is important. Consider this: `operator std::string & (void) { std::string dangerous; return dangerous; }` versus `operator std::string (void) { std::string not_dangerous; return not_dangerous; }`